# Why didn't the Prophet Muhammad choose to stay alive longer?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets

I read that prophets/messengers can choose to live as long as they like with permission from God to spread the message, such as prophet Noah.

Why didn't he stay alive for maybe another 300 years? This way every soul on earth would probably believe in him as being supported by God. This way the Hadith wouldn't be a clobbered mess like it is today. Why leave so early? If he was so worried about his Ummah why wouldn't he have stayed the next 5000 years to guide everyone?

Why not be like prophet Noah who lived up to 950 years? Wouldn't that make Prophet Noah the greatest prophet of all time rather than Muhammad? Living so many life times of difficulty to spread his religion?

What's the point in caring about the 'ummah' so much when you could've done a HELL of a lot more?

Sahih Bukhari
Chapter: 8, Prayers (Salat)

Hadith No: 455
Narrated/Authority of Abu Said Al-Khudri
The Prophet delivered a sermon and said, **"Allah gave a choice to one of (His) slaves either to choose this world or what is with Him in the Hereafter. He chose the latter." Abu Bakr wept. I said lo myself, "Why is this Sheikh weeping, if Allah gave choice to one (of His) slaves either to choose this world or what is with Him in the Here after and he chose the latter?" And that slave was Allah's Apostle himself.** Abu Bakr knew more than us. The Prophet said, "O Abu Bakr! Don't weep. The Prophet added: Abu- Bakr has favored me much with his property and company. If I were to take a Khalil from mankind I would certainly have taken Abu Bakr but the Islamic brotherhood and friendship is sufficient. Close all the gates in the mosque except that of Abu Bakr.

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kHFvjpewe5AC&pg=PT89&lpg=PT89&dq=Allah+gave+a+choice+to+one+of+His+slaves+either+to+choose+this+world+or+what+is+with+Him.+That+slave+what+is+with+Allah&source=bl&ots=0NV0L3Ks5n&sig=ACfU3U3lPyiH-RRPJ3I7Z7rqX8JdNtTkeg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=allah%20gave%20a%20choice&f=false

Comment: You seem to not understand that everything happens according to Allah's will. A person's remaining alive or passing on will not change what is going to happen nor when it is going to happen, and Allah's promise will take hold no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

The hadith you base it on does not say what you think it says.

The hadith is that:

> Allah gave a choice to one of (His) slaves either to choose this world or what is with Him in the Hereafter. He chose the latter. ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/114))

The obvious meaning is that Allah gave the messenger the choice to stay in the world and see the fruition of Muslim victory that was about to come in the next decades, or come to Allah.

To make this meaning more obvious, there are other narrations that have a similar implication to this:

> Jibreel sat with the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) and he looked at the sky and saw an angel coming down. Jibreel said: This angel has never come down since the day he was created, until now. When he had come down, he said: O Muhammad, your Lord has sent me to you (to give you the choice of being) either a Prophet-king or a Messenger-slave. Jibreel said: Be humble before your Lord, O Muhammad. He said: “Rather (I choose to be) a Messenger-slave.” (Musnad Imam Ahmad)

In this narration as well, the Prophet (SAW) was given the choice between being able to be a great ruler like his successors were going to be, or die as a humble messenger.

This choice was given because his job as a messenger was already complete, and it was just a matter of reward at that point.

So, Allah gave him the choice: watch the good things of the world, or come back to Allah without watching them.

The Prophet (SAW) chose the latter.

There is no implication that the Prophet (SAW) could have lived for 300 years. It would only have taken 20 more years to watch the world be conquered by Muslims.

Comment: @Jeff There is no doubt his job as a messenger was complete. A verse in the Quran was even revealed. "This day I have completed your religion [...]" Your problem with the hadith is not relevant and the comments are not a place to have that discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Why did not Muhammad choose to live longer?
In Kafi book and also other Shiite sources have written: The imams know when they will die, and they do not die unless they choose them.”[1] "Imams know when they die and they do not die except of their own free will."

It is death and events that result from the inner malice of the oppressors, sinners and infidels, God knows it and has informed his special servants like the prophets and imams about it, but he has not prevented it so that the divine test can be achieved; Like the oppression of the Prophet of Islam by the pagans, the Jews and the hypocrites in Mecca and Medina. That the Prophet described some of them as; He endured the persecution of the polytheists in Mecca and the battle of Uhud, etc., and in some cases he was sent to special reactions; Such as emigrating because of the conspiracy of the polytheists to kill that Imam on the night of Al-Mubayt.
{And every nation has a term, so when their term comes, they do not delay it an hour, nor do they advance}(Araf: on them 4).

There is a definite time for every people and people, and when their time comes, they will not be late for an hour nor will they be ahead of it. (2)
[1]. Kafi, vol. 1, p. 258.

(2)Ref: https://hajj.ir/fa/86024